# Parsing Xml using Python to find the certain node values

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

Below is the xml code

```
<databases>
            <source>
                    <host>prod</host>
                    <port>1522</port>
                    <user>P11</user>
                    <password>lXXXXX</password>
                    <tns>GP1</tns>

            </source>
            <target>
                    <host>bcp</host>
                    <port>1522</port>
                    <user>pg</user>
                    <password>yyyyy</password>
            </target>
    </databases>
```

Now want print the value of "user" and "tns" if "tns" is present else print null.Tried using Etree lxml but not getting the desired results.
Thanks.

Comment: Which items do you want to print?

Comment: edited the question want to print user and tns if tns is present

Comment: I assume that you have a large file which includes multiple `<database>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got the result thanks for your prompt replies**

```
 failures = {}
try:
    doc = etree.parse(os.path.join(my_result_dir_name,file_whichI_wanted_to_parse))
    root = doc.getroot()
    for case in root.findall(".//databases"):
        user = case.find("user").text
        tnsTag = case.find("tns")
        if tnsTag is None:
            continue
        failures[user] = (tns.text) if len(errorStackTraceTag.text) > 200 else errorStackTraceTag.text
    return failures
except (Exception,IOError), e:
    return  {
        "error":str(e)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the python-pip package

```
sudo apt-get install -yq python-pip #for debian-based OSs like ubuntu
```

install the xmltodict python package from console (using pip)

```
pip install xmltodict
```

in python

```
import xmltodict

myDict=xmltodict.parse(my_xml_string)
print myDict['databases']['source']['user']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have multiple `databases` tags nested in a `root` parent node. Read your content into a string (I am using a multi-line Python string)

```
my_string  = '''
<root>
  <databases>
    <source>
        <host>prod</host>
        <port>1522</port>
        <user>P11</user>
        <password>lXXXXX</password>
        <tns>GP1</tns>
    </source>
    <target>
        <host>bcp</host>
        <port>1522</port>
        <user>pg</user>
        <password>yyyyy</password>
    </target>
  </databases>
</root>
'''
```

You can then achieve the desired results with the following:

```
from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring(my_string)
databases = tree.xpath('.//databases')

for database in databases:
    print('User: ' + database.xpath('.//user/text()')[0])
    try: 
        print('TNS: ' + database.xpath('.//tns/text()')[0])
    except:
        print('TNS: null')
```